# How to sub string the value of XML element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert the value of XML element into some other format e.g KG to LBS. 
Let say I have a XML

```
<all>
    <one>Something 1</one>
    <two>something 2</two>
    <check>
        <present>true</present>
    </check>
    <action>
        <perform></perform>
    </action>
    <a>
        <Weight>1Kg</Weight>
    </a>
</all>
```

after XSLT my expected output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><all>
<one>Something 1</one>
<two>something 2</two>
<check>
<present>true</present>
</check>
<action>
<perform/>
</action>
<a>
<UNIT-WEIGHT>2.2046226218487757</UNIT-WEIGHT>
</a>
</all>
```

for this I write

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match= "@*|node()" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select= "@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template >

<xsl:template match="Weight">
    <UNIT-WEIGHT>
      <xsl:value-of select=". div 0.45359237"/>
    </UNIT-WEIGHT>
    </xsl:template>
```

If `<Weight>1</Weight>` I get my desired output & if `<Weight>1Kg</Weight>` I get `<UNIT-WEIGHT>NaN</UNIT-WEIGHT>`

What I need to do ??

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '') div 0.45359237"/>  try with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to know what exactly *can* be the value of `Weight` before answering this. One or two examples do not disclose a rule.

Try perhaps:

```
<xsl:template match="Weight">
    <UNIT-WEIGHT>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., translate(., '.0123456789', ''), '') div 0.45359237"/>
    </UNIT-WEIGHT>
</xsl:template>
```

This will filter out all characters except digits and decimal point, which are necessary to construct a valid number (assuming a weight cannot be negative).

Note that this will fail with a value such as:

```
<Weight>1.5 kg.</Weight>
```

because `1.5.` is not a valid number.

Comment: Is there any logic that can be applicable which could be worked in `<Weight>1.5kg</Weight>`. . ??

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh The above will work perfectly well with `<Weight>1.5kg</Weight>`.