# How to perform XSL to remove the text from xml tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLECTION>
<Added>
<part>
<weight>5kg</weight>

</part>
<part>
<weight></weight>
</part>
<part>
<weight>2kg</weight>
</part>
</Added>
<Update>
<part>
<weight></weight>
</part>
<part>
<weight>3kg</weight>
</part>
<part>
<weight>2kg</weight>
</part>
</Update>
</COLLECTION>
```

I want to apply XSL on it such that `<weight>` tag need to convert to `Weight` and consider the only number.With this I want to add some extra tag which is not present in input XML.`<unitWeights>` if the value of `<weight>` is presnt only and only then it will show KG rest it will be blank.

expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLECTION>
<Added>
<part>
<Weight>5</Weight>
<unitWeights>KG</unitWeights>
</part>
<part>
<Weight></Weight>
<unitWeights></unitWeights>
</part>
<part>
<Weight>2</Weight>
<unitWeights>KG</unitWeights>
</part>
</Added>
<Update>
<part>
<Weight></Weight>
<unitWeights></unitWeights>
</part>
<part>
<Weight>3</Weight>
<unitWeights>KG</unitWeights>
</part>
<part>
<Weight>2</Weight>
<unitWeights>KG</unitWeights>
</part>
</Update>
</COLLECTION>
```

for this i have applied :

```
    <xsl:template match="Weight">
    <weight>
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')"/>
    </weight>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="WeightUnits">
    <unitWeights>KG</unitWeights>
    </xsl:template>
```

Please help me out where i am wrong.

Comment: Déjà vu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847633/how-to-sub-string-the-value-of-xml-element-using-xslt/38848039#38848039

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="weight">
    <Weight>
      <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before(.,'kg')"/>
    </Weight>

    <unitWeights>
      <xsl:copy-of select="substring(., string-length(.) - 1)"/>
    </unitWeights>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="unitWeights"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks . Just need to ask one more question what if <unitWeights> is already there and i want to mark it as KG only if some value is present in Weight

Comment: @PeterJohn - Add `<xsl:template match="unitWeights"/>`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrol : I changed to `<xsl:template match="Weight">
    <weight>
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')"/>
    </weight>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="WeightUnits">
   <unitWeights>KG</unitWeights>
    </xsl:template>`

Answer (score 1):

Following is a generic solution for your requirement.

1. For only node which 'weight', you need to process or apply template to.

   ```
   <xsl:template match="weight">
   ```
2. Then you need to apply `translate` as mentioned in this to extract only string part and only digits parts.
      [XPath - extract numeric value out of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891008/xpath-extract-numeric-value-out-of-string)

Demo for you : http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHb/23

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://locomotive/bypass/docx" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="weight">

    <xsl:variable name="currentWeight" select="translate(.,translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')" />
    <xsl:variable name="currentWeightUnit" select="translate(., '0123456789', '')" />

     <xsl:if test="string-length($currentWeight) &gt; 0">
         <Weight>
            <xsl:value-of select="$currentWeight"/>
        </Weight>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($currentWeightUnit) &gt; 0">
           <unitWeights>
             <xsl:value-of select="$currentWeightUnit"/>
           </unitWeights>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In unitWeight i want as 'KG' only if the data is present in XML weight tag

Comment: also it wout be better if i modify exiesting <unitWeights> tag insted of adding.

Comment: @PeterJohn try updated answer. It will add only if weight is having any value and within that unitWeight only if KG is present

Comment: @PeterJohn you do not have any <unitWeights> tag in your actual input XML so it needs to be added and can not be modified